# Unabled to SSH into Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created AWS free tier account for practicing certification. I am facing issue in SSHing to the instance from laptop and the browser based EC2 CLI.

I am using the ssh command shown in connect manual.

I changed the outgoing rule for security group to custom to point to my ip but  got same results.
(Custom)
SSH, TCP, 22,19x.xx.xx.xx/32

(Anywhere)
SSH, TCP, 22, 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

I tried the same in couple in other availability zone but could not ssh.

Comment: Does your Ec2 is in Public subnet ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html

Answer (score 0):

question is not clear prassank... if you are trying to access from your machine to aws ec2. Please allow your ISP(Internet service provider) ip  into inbound rule of security group. Please do not open to all. as it is breaching the security to your system.

In case of you are not able.please do let me know.

Comment: I am trying to ssh into my ec2 instance, the security group has  source as anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) . Are you asking me change the source to connect to ec2 as myip/32. I am  trying this out from my office network  could there be sec policy setting that is not allowing ssh?. I have free tier account I ll be creating instances and removing will connect from anywhere cause issues

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Free Tier is a pricing discount. It has no impact on how your services operate, so is not relevant for your situation.

Things to check when trying to SSH into the EC2 instance:

- The EC2 instance should be in a **public subnet**
- You should connect using the EC2 instance's **public IP address**
- The **Security Group** associated with the EC2 instance should permit:

  - **Inbound access** from your IP address on port 22
  - It is recommended to leave the default **outbound access** to permit ALL traffic on ALL ports